# use Executors.callable() within lambda

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have the following which works:

```
var tasks = tasks.stream(a -> (Callable<Set<FinishedTask>>) () -> call(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I want to change the above code to use `Executors.callable`

```
// how to cast executor.callable?
var tasks = tasks.stream(t -> (Set<FinishedTask>)Executors.callable(()-> call(t))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, I get the compiler error:

```
The method callable(Runnable) is ambiguous for the type Executors
```

What is wrong with the cast?

Comment: Why do you want to use Executors.callable? You already have a Callable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here.

First this type of error, java cannot infer which method to call.

```
Callable<?> c = Executors.callable( (PrivilegedAction) () -> "tested" );
```

By using a cast you can tell java to use Executors.callable(PrivilegedAction) instead of Executors.callable(PrivilegedExceptionAction). They both have the same method signature. Runnable is not mistaken in this case because it is a void return type.

Second, now it will know which method to use, but it is still returning a Callable, so you cannot just cast it to a set.

```
Callable<Set<FinishedTask>> callable = () -> call(a);
Callable<Set<FinishedTask>> callable2 = Executors.callable(()-> call(t));
```

You're trying to **cast** to a set. You need to call.

```
Set<FinishedTask> sft = Executors.callable(()-> call(t)).call();
```